# Is there a way to divide two dataframes in the following way and get the desired output as shown below?

Tags: r

```
> z
  Jan20 Feb21 Mar21 Apr21 May21 Jun21
1  8026  4464  3806  3799  2466  2388
2     0  4743  4877  4769  2008  1503
3     0     0  4516  4474  1532  1160
4     0     0     0  4867  1078  1384
5     0     0     0     0  1274  1439
6     0     0     0     0     0  1359

> x
  Jan20 Feb21 Mar21 Apr21 May21 Jun21
1  6093  2949   781   571  1202  1359
2  6093  2949   781   571  1202  1359
3  6093  2949   781   571  1202  1359
4  6093  2949   781   571  1202  1359
5  6093  2949   781   571  1202  1359
6  6093  2949   781   571  1202  1359

> x/z
      Jan20     Feb21     Mar21     Apr21     May21     Jun21
1 0.7591577 0.6606183 0.2052023 0.1503027 0.4874290 0.5690955
2       Inf 0.6217584 0.1601394 0.1197316 0.5986056 0.9041916
3       Inf       Inf 0.1729407 0.1276263 0.7845953 1.1715517
4       Inf       Inf       Inf 0.1173207 1.1150278 0.9819364
5       Inf       Inf       Inf       Inf 0.9434851 0.9444058
6       Inf       Inf       Inf       Inf       Inf 1.0000000

w <- w %>% mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(is.infinite(x), 0, x))

> w
      Jan20     Feb21     Mar21     Apr21     May21     Jun21
1 0.7591577 0.6606183 0.2052023 0.1503027 0.4874290 0.5690955
2 0.0000000 0.6217584 0.1601394 0.1197316 0.5986056 0.9041916
3 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1729407 0.1276263 0.7845953 1.1715517
4 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1173207 1.1150278 0.9819364
5 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.9434851 0.9444058
6 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000

Now I want the output as follows
Jan20 0.7591577 0.6217584 0.1729407 0.1173207 0.9434851 1.0000000
Feb21 0.6606183 0.1601394 0.1276263 1.1150278 0.9444058 0
Mar21 0.2052023 0.1197316 0.7845953 0.9819364 0 0
Apr21 0.1503027 0.5986056 1.1715517 0 0 0
```

Like the above I am looking for the output. Let me know what options we have it for this.

Thanks
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply` to loop over the rows, remove the 0s and return a `list`

```
w_lst <-  lapply(split(as.matrix(w), t(apply(col(w) > row(w),
          1, cumsum))), setdiff, 0)
names(w_lst) <- names(w)
mx <- max(lengths(w_lst))
w_lst1 <- lapply(w_lst, function(x) {length(x) <- mx
           replace(x, is.na(x), 0)
    })
```

-output

```
w_lst1
#$Jan20
#[1] 0.7591577 0.6217584 0.1729407 0.1173207 0.9434851 1.0000000

#$Feb21
#[1] 0.6606183 0.1601394 0.1276263 1.1150278 0.9444058 0.0000000

#$Mar21
#[1] 0.2052023 0.1197316 0.7845953 0.9819364 0.0000000 0.0000000

#$Apr21
#[1] 0.1503027 0.5986056 1.1715517 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000

#$May21
#[1] 0.4874290 0.9041916 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000

#$Jun21
#[1] 0.5690955 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. I think we need to "w[is.infinite(w)] <- 0" this first as i m seeing the "Inf" in the output fin the first row.

Comment: @RohitGosain I assumed that you have used `w <- w %>% mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(is.infinite(x), 0, x))` in your code

Answer (score 1):

in base R you could do:

```
w <- as.matrix(x/z)
w[is.infinite(w)] <- 0
grp <- col(w) - row(w)
grp[grp < 0] <- grp[grp < 0] + ncol(w)
do.call(rbind,setNames(split(t(w), t(grp)), names(x)))
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5] [,6]
Jan20 0.7591577 0.6217584 0.1729407 0.1173207 0.9434851    1
Feb21 0.6606183 0.1601394 0.1276263 1.1150278 0.9444058    0
Mar21 0.2052023 0.1197316 0.7845953 0.9819364 0.0000000    0
Apr21 0.1503027 0.5986056 1.1715517 0.0000000 0.0000000    0
May21 0.4874290 0.9041916 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0
Jun21 0.5690955 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0
```

Comment: Thanks Onyambu. Is it possible to remove the "Jan20, Feb21...Jun21" from the output ?

Comment: This is what i did and it worked...."a <- do.call(rbind,setNames(split(t(w), t(grp)), names(x))) and then a<- as.data.frame(a, row.names=F). Thanks for your help.....

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

(w <- matrix(
  c(
    0.7591577, 0.6606183, 0.2052023, 0.1503027, 0.487429, 0.5690955, 
    0, 0.6217584, 0.1601394, 0.1197316, 0.5986056, 0.9041916, 
    0, 0, 0.1729407, 0.1276263, 0.7845953, 1.1715517, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.1173207, 1.1150278, 0.9819364, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9434851, 0.9444058, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
  ),
  nrow = 6, 
  byrow = TRUE
))
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
#> [1,] 0.7591577 0.6606183 0.2052023 0.1503027 0.4874290 0.5690955
#> [2,] 0.0000000 0.6217584 0.1601394 0.1197316 0.5986056 0.9041916
#> [3,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1729407 0.1276263 0.7845953 1.1715517
#> [4,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1173207 1.1150278 0.9819364
#> [5,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.9434851 0.9444058
#> [6,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000

helper <- function(mat, col_index) {
  mat_subset <- mat[, col_index:ncol(mat)]
  
  if (col_index != ncol(mat)) {
    # t() converts a vector into a 1-row matrix
    t(diag(mat_subset)) 
  } else {
    # inner t() ensures that last col is passed as a matrix to diag()
    t(diag(t(mat_subset)))  
  }
}

map_dfr(1:ncol(w), ~ as_tibble(helper(w, .x))) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(.x, 0)))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.759 0.622 0.173 0.117 0.943     1
#> 2 0.661 0.160 0.128 1.12  0.944     0
#> 3 0.205 0.120 0.785 0.982 0         0
#> 4 0.150 0.599 1.17  0     0         0
#> 5 0.487 0.904 0     0     0         0
#> 6 0.569 0     0     0     0         0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>